# Test system stability on Debian 12 laptop after undervolting

Tags: debian, laptop

I want to undervolt my Debian 12 laptop with [Undervolt](https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt). What is a good way to test the stability of both the CPU and the iGPU quickly?